# Building tf.data pipeline with list of files i.e. pickle dataframe

Tags: python, tensorflow, data-preprocessing

I am not able to build the `tf.data` pipeline (with Tensorflow 2.1.0 on python 3.7.7 & Windows 10) for a list of pickled dataframes. To get started use the below code:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import os, pickle
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.keras.preprocessing.sequence import pad_sequences
from sklearn.preprocessing import MultiLabelBinarizer

MAX_LEN = 8
NULL_VALUE = -1

# creating the sample dataframe
df = pd.DataFrame({'SOURCE': [[0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0], [0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 2, 2, 2], [0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1], [-1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1], [0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1]], 'TIME': [[0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 2], [0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 2, 7, 2, 2, 2], [0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1], [-1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1], [0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 2, 7]], 'DATE': [[0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 2], [0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 2, 7, 2, 2, 2], [0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1], [-1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1], [0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 2, 7]], 'CAT_AF1': [[1, 2, 3, 4], [1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 2], [0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 2, 7, 2, 2, 2], [1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3], [-1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1], [0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 2, 7]], 'CAT_AF2': [[1, 2, 3, 4], [1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 2], [0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 2, 7, 2, 2, 2], [1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3], [-1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1], [0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 2, 7]], 'PROD': [[1, 2, 3, 4], [1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 2], [0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 2, 7, 2, 2, 2], [1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3], [-1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1], [0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 2, 7]], 'PROD_Y': [[1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3, 4], [1], [7], [3], [1, 2], [0], [2]]})

FEATURES = [col for col in df.columns if col != 'PROD_Y']

# saving the same dataframe as multiple pickle files
os.mkdir('data')
os.mkdir(os.path.join('data', 'pickles'))

for n in range(10):
    with open(os.path.join('data', 'pickles', 'pickle-n-{n}.pkl'.format(n=n)), 'wb') as f:
        pickle.dump(df, f, pickle.HIGHEST_PROTOCOL)

def read_pickles(filename):
    with open(filename, 'rb') as f:
        df_ = pickle.load(f)
    return df_

def pad_(x):
    return pad_sequences([x], dtype=np.int32, maxlen=MAX_LEN, padding='pre', truncating='pre', value=NULL_VALUE)[0]

def parse_files(filename):
    df_ = read_pickles(filename)
    MLB = MultiLabelBinarizer(classes=list(set([j for i in df_['PROD_Y'].tolist() for j in i])))
    MLB.fit(y=df_['PROD_Y'])
    for col in FEATURES:
        df_[col] = df_[col].apply(pad_)
    df_['PROD_Y'] = MLB.transform(df_['PROD_Y']).tolist()
    
    return dict(df_) 
    # return tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(dict(df_)) 
    # return df_.to_dict('list')

def parse_(filename):
    out = tf.py_function(parse_files, inp=[filename], Tout=[tf.float32 for k in FEATURES]) # not sure how to write the dict returned into Tout argument
    return out

list_of_files = [os.path.join('data', 'pickles', f) for f in os.listdir(os.path.join('data', 'pickles'))]

dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(list_of_files)
dataset_2 = dataset.map(parse_)
a = [d for d in dataset_2]
```

On the last line, it throws the following error within `read_pickles`:

`UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xb0 in position 0: invalid start byte`

I tried using `filename.decode('utf-8')` within `read_pickles` but that also leads to another error:
`AttributeError: 'tensorflow.python.framework.ops.EagerTensor' object has no attribute 'decode'`

When I searched about it, I found these but they didnt help with the issue:

- [tf.py_function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50870126/how-to-load-pickle-files-by-tensorflows-tf-data-api)
- [Maybe it is related to this issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61131730/tensorflow-datasets-with-string-inputs-do-not-preserve-data-type)

Full traceback:

```
2021-05-16 19:59:01.568800: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:44] Successfully opened dynamic library cudart64_101.dll
2021-05-16 19:59:04.926696: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:44] Successfully opened dynamic library nvcuda.dll
2021-05-16 19:59:06.100711: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1555] Found device 0 with properties: 
pciBusID: 0000:01:00.0 name: GeForce GTX 1660 Ti computeCapability: 7.5
coreClock: 1.59GHz coreCount: 24 deviceMemorySize: 6.00GiB deviceMemoryBandwidth: 268.26GiB/s
2021-05-16 19:59:06.100787: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:44] Successfully opened dynamic library cudart64_101.dll
2021-05-16 19:59:06.109139: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:44] Successfully opened dynamic library cublas64_10.dll
2021-05-16 19:59:06.114618: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:44] Successfully opened dynamic library cufft64_10.dll
2021-05-16 19:59:06.117511: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:44] Successfully opened dynamic library curand64_10.dll
2021-05-16 19:59:06.124338: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:44] Successfully opened dynamic library cusolver64_10.dll
2021-05-16 19:59:06.129912: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:44] Successfully opened dynamic library cusparse64_10.dll
2021-05-16 19:59:06.142492: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:44] Successfully opened dynamic library cudnn64_7.dll
2021-05-16 19:59:06.142600: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1697] Adding visible gpu devices: 0
2021-05-16 19:59:06.143031: I tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:142] Your CPU supports instructions that this TensorFlow binary was not compiled to use: AVX2
2021-05-16 19:59:06.144206: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1555] Found device 0 with properties: 
pciBusID: 0000:01:00.0 name: GeForce GTX 1660 Ti computeCapability: 7.5
coreClock: 1.59GHz coreCount: 24 deviceMemorySize: 6.00GiB deviceMemoryBandwidth: 268.26GiB/s
2021-05-16 19:59:06.144245: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:44] Successfully opened dynamic library cudart64_101.dll
2021-05-16 19:59:06.144265: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:44] Successfully opened dynamic library cublas64_10.dll
2021-05-16 19:59:06.144281: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:44] Successfully opened dynamic library cufft64_10.dll
2021-05-16 19:59:06.144299: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:44] Successfully opened dynamic library curand64_10.dll
2021-05-16 19:59:06.144314: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:44] Successfully opened dynamic library cusolver64_10.dll
2021-05-16 19:59:06.144328: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:44] Successfully opened dynamic library cusparse64_10.dll
2021-05-16 19:59:06.144343: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:44] Successfully opened dynamic library cudnn64_7.dll
2021-05-16 19:59:06.144390: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1697] Adding visible gpu devices: 0
2021-05-16 19:59:06.866245: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1096] Device interconnect StreamExecutor with strength 1 edge matrix:
2021-05-16 19:59:06.866285: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1102]      0 
2021-05-16 19:59:06.866300: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1115] 0:   N 
2021-05-16 19:59:06.866531: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1241] Created TensorFlow device (/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0 with 4755 MB memory) -> physical GPU (device: 0, name: GeForce GTX 1660 Ti, pci bus id: 0000:01:00.0, compute capability: 7.5)
2021-05-16 19:59:07.063641: W tensorflow/core/framework/op_kernel.cc:1643] Invalid argument: UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xb0 in position 0: invalid start byte
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "C:\Users\D\Miniconda3\envs\Dev\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\ops\script_ops.py", line 234, in __call__
    return func(device, token, args)

  File "C:\Users\D\Miniconda3\envs\Dev\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\ops\script_ops.py", line 123, in __call__
    ret = self._func(*args)

  File "stack-overflow-tf-data-question.py", line 33, in parse_files
    df_ = read_pickles(filename)

  File "stack-overflow-tf-data-question.py", line 25, in read_pickles
    with open(filename, 'rb') as f:

UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xb0 in position 0: invalid start byte


2021-05-16 19:59:07.063812: W tensorflow/core/framework/op_kernel.cc:1655] OP_REQUIRES failed at iterator_ops.cc:941 : Invalid argument: UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xb0 in position 0: invalid start byte
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "C:\Users\D\Miniconda3\envs\Dev\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\ops\script_ops.py", line 234, in __call__
    return func(device, token, args)

  File "C:\Users\D\Miniconda3\envs\Dev\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\ops\script_ops.py", line 123, in __call__
    ret = self._func(*args)

  File "stack-overflow-tf-data-question.py", line 33, in parse_files
    df_ = read_pickles(filename)

  File "stack-overflow-tf-data-question.py", line 25, in read_pickles
    with open(filename, 'rb') as f:

UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xb0 in position 0: invalid start byte


     [[{{node EagerPyFunc}}]]
stack-overflow-tf-data-question.py:25: DeprecationWarning: path should be string, bytes, or os.PathLike, not tensorflow.python.framework.ops.EagerTensor
  with open(filename, 'rb') as f:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\D\Miniconda3\envs\Dev\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\eager\context.py", line 1897, in execution_mode
    yield
  File "C:\Users\D\Miniconda3\envs\Dev\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\data\ops\iterator_ops.py", line 659, in _next_internal
    output_shapes=self._flat_output_shapes)
  File "C:\Users\D\Miniconda3\envs\Dev\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\ops\gen_dataset_ops.py", line 2479, in iterator_get_next_sync
    _ops.raise_from_not_ok_status(e, name)
  File "C:\Users\D\Miniconda3\envs\Dev\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\framework\ops.py", line 6606, in raise_from_not_ok_status
    six.raise_from(core._status_to_exception(e.code, message), None)
  File "<string>", line 3, in raise_from
tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.InvalidArgumentError: UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xb0 in position 0: invalid start byte
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "C:\Users\D\Miniconda3\envs\Dev\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\ops\script_ops.py", line 234, in __call__
    return func(device, token, args)

  File "C:\Users\D\Miniconda3\envs\Dev\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\ops\script_ops.py", line 123, in __call__
    ret = self._func(*args)

  File "stack-overflow-tf-data-question.py", line 33, in parse_files
    df_ = read_pickles(filename)

  File "stack-overflow-tf-data-question.py", line 25, in read_pickles
    with open(filename, 'rb') as f:

UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xb0 in position 0: invalid start byte


     [[{{node EagerPyFunc}}]] [Op:IteratorGetNextSync]

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "stack-overflow-tf-data-question.py", line 52, in <module>
    a = [d for d in dataset_2]
  File "stack-overflow-tf-data-question.py", line 52, in <listcomp>
    a = [d for d in dataset_2]
  File "C:\Users\D\Miniconda3\envs\Dev\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\data\ops\iterator_ops.py", line 630, in __next__
    return self.next()
  File "C:\Users\D\Miniconda3\envs\Dev\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\data\ops\iterator_ops.py", line 674, in next
    return self._next_internal()
  File "C:\Users\D\Miniconda3\envs\Dev\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\data\ops\iterator_ops.py", line 665, in _next_internal
    return structure.from_compatible_tensor_list(self._element_spec, ret)
  File "C:\Users\D\Miniconda3\envs\Dev\lib\contextlib.py", line 130, in __exit__
    self.gen.throw(type, value, traceback)
  File "C:\Users\D\Miniconda3\envs\Dev\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\eager\context.py", line 1900, in execution_mode
    executor_new.wait()
  File "C:\Users\D\Miniconda3\envs\Dev\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\eager\executor.py", line 67, in wait
    pywrap_tensorflow.TFE_ExecutorWaitForAllPendingNodes(self._handle)
tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.InvalidArgumentError: UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xb0 in position 0: invalid start byte
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "C:\Users\D\Miniconda3\envs\Dev\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\ops\script_ops.py", line 234, in __call__
    return func(device, token, args)

  File "C:\Users\D\Miniconda3\envs\Dev\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\ops\script_ops.py", line 123, in __call__
    ret = self._func(*args)

  File "stack-overflow-tf-data-question.py", line 33, in parse_files
    df_ = read_pickles(filename)

  File "stack-overflow-tf-data-question.py", line 25, in read_pickles
    with open(filename, 'rb') as f:

UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xb0 in position 0: invalid start byte


     [[{{node EagerPyFunc}}]]
```

Appreciate your help! TIA!

Answer (score 0):

Replace read_pickles function as

```
def read_pickles(filename):
    with open(filename, 'rb', encoding="utf8") as f:
        df_ = pickle.load(f)
    return df_
```

Comment: Hi @TFer, when I run the pipeline it says:

  File "stack-overflow-tf-data-answer.py", line 33, in parse_files
    df_ = read_pickles(filename)

  File "stack-overflow-tf-data-answer.py", line 25, in read_pickles
    with open(filename, 'rb', encoding="utf8") as f:

ValueError: binary mode doesn't take an encoding argument
         [[{{node EagerPyFunc}}]] [Op:IteratorGetNextSync]

Comment: Try this way `open(filename, 'r', encoding="utf8")`.

Comment: Normally reading it raises the following error:
`  File "stack-overflow-tf-data-answer.py", line 33, in parse_files
    df_ = read_pickles(filename)

  File "stack-overflow-tf-data-answer.py", line 25, in read_pickles
    with open(filename, 'r', encoding="utf8") as f:

UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xb5 in position 2: invalid start byte


         [[{{node EagerPyFunc}}]]`

Comment: Error is because there might be some non-ascii character in the file and it can't be encoded/decoded. One simple way to avoid this error is to encode such strings with encode(). `x.encode('utf-8').strip()`. OR Use different encoding such as `encoding = 'unicode_escape'`. Thanks!